# Updating Store with new rest url dynamically. Extjs4

Tags: load, extjs4, store

I have two tabs in my application. First show the search results in a grid and second tab has a grid (uses "Details store") which shows details.

I am constructing rest url on click of search result. How do I dynamically update "details store" with new url to get new JSON records.

One way is to use EXt.Ajax.request and get the results and use store load method. 
Is there any more elegant way.

Comment: The store's load method should do the ajax request for you.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the stores are different instances and are not shared between grids. 
then use whatever handler you got to set the URL and load:

```
grid.store.getProxy().url = 'request/my.json';
grid.store.load();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar scenario. I had a parent grid. Based on user selection, another child grid has to be refreshed with a different URL. The solution suggested by DmitryB worked. Thanks a lot.